# Auto load void;0 on page load

Tags: javascript, web

Hello I need to add a chat function to my apps and the only thing I think is to create in a webview the chat emerge, In my web the chats opens with: `javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())`

so i think in something like this:

```
function load()
{
    window.location.href = "javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())";
}
```

But no working, could is this possible? I need in this web to on page load auto pop up the widget chat.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just call `Tawk_API.toggle()`?

Comment: Im really newbie at this, I changed the part of that code to that and nothing happens, here you can see my test html : http://zoobaby.com.uy/chat.html

Comment: Where are you calling `load()`?

Comment: in <head> it is wrong?

Comment: No, where are you *calling* it, not where you're placing it. It doesn't just magically run itself.

Comment: I added the text "Click to chat", that is what I want to open on page load.

Comment: Could you help me with the missing code?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", Tawk_API.toggle);`

Comment: @epascarello like this? <script>
window.addEventListener("load", Tawk_API.toggle();
</script>

Comment: @MaximilianoHeijo well you have a typo in yours compared to mine.